# Ruby bundle console is not loading aws shared credentials from ~/.aws/credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby, gem-bundler

How can I load aws credentials to ruby if I use bundler console.

Scenario:

I have the following code in samplefile.rb and aws credentials in ~/.aws/credentials

```
require 'aws-sdk-core'
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
require 'json'

class Publisher
    def listBuckets
        profile_name = 'AWSConsumer'
        region = "us-east-1"
        s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(profile: profile_name, region:region)
        resp = s3.list_buckets
        resp.buckets.each do |bucket|
        puts bucket.name
    end
end
Publisher.new.listBuckets
```

This is working fine by taking the shared credentials 
when I use 
    $ruby samplefile.rb

but when I execute the same using 
$bundle exec bin/console

Getting missing credentials .

> missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following
>   options:
>     - :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
>     - :credentials
>     - :credentials_provider

As per the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com//sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html#aws-ruby-sdk-credentials-shared), its should load the shared credentials for ruby.